# Can anybody help me with this logarithm problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $(\log_4 x)^2= (\log_2 x)(\log_a x)$ (the $4$ is the little number next to log by the way) , find the value of $a$.

Comment: i've tempted an edit. Is it correct?

Comment: use the identity $\log_a(x) = \log(x) / \log(a)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\log_4x=\frac{\log_2x}{\log_24}$$

and thus your equation is simply

$$\frac{\log^2_2x}{\log^2_24}=\log_2x\cdot\log_ax$$

You may also want to remember that $\;\log_by^n=n\log_by\;$

Answer (score 2):

Use the change of basis formula $ \log_b(x)=\dfrac{\log_c x}{\log_c b}$ and find:
$$
\log_4 x =\dfrac{\log_2 x}{2}
$$
so your equation become:
$$
\log_a x=\dfrac{(\log_2 x)^2}{4 \log_2 x}=\dfrac{\log_2 x}{4}
$$
and using the same formula you find:
$$
\log_2 a=4 \Rightarrow a=16
$$

Answer (score 1):

$log_4x=\dfrac{log_2x}{log_24}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assuming $x>0, x\neq 1$, your equation is equivalent to:

$$\left(\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_2 4}\right)^2=\log_2 x\left(\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_2 a}\right)$$

Divide both sides by $\left(\log_2 x\right)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If we let $x=4$, we have:

$$(\log_4 4)^2 = (\log_2 4) (\log_a 4)$$
$$ 1 = 2 \log_a 4 $$
$$\frac12 = \log_a 4$$
$$a^{1/2} = 4$$
$$a = 4^2 = 16$$

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the logarithms to ones with the same base as follows.
$$(\log_4 x)^2 = (\log_2 x)(\log_a x)$$
$$(\log_4 x)^2 = (\frac{\log_4 x}{\log_4 2})(\frac{\log_4 x}{\log_4 a})$$
$$\dots$$

All that's left to show is that $\displaystyle\log_a x = \frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}$

$$\log_a x = \frac{(\log_a x)(\log_b a)}{\log_b a}=\frac{\log_b a^{\log_a x}}{\log_b a}=\frac{\log_b x}{\log_b a}$$